# Achieve similar hardware acceleration optimization in Android 2.3 - Avoid multiple onDraw call

Tags: android

By referring to http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html#accelerate, I know that I can avoid multiple system call on busy `onDraw` by using `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);`.

I tested on Android 4, by performing home -> restore -> home. I realize `onDraw` will only be called once as stated in the above android documentation.

However, how can I achieve the similar optimization in Android 2.3? As Android 2.3 doesn't support hardware optimization.

```
public class PieChart extends View {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public PieChart(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mPiePaint = new Paint();
        mPiePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPiePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPiePaint.setColor(0x88FF0000);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if (!isInEditMode()) {
                setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Log.i("CHEOK", "Busy onDraw is called");

        canvas.drawArc(mBounds,
                0,
                200,
                true, mPiePaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mBounds = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    private RectF mBounds;    
    private Paint mPiePaint;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should try is 2 versions of this class.

The first one will be used only by hardware-accelerated devices, and will use the optimisation explained in the google documentations

For devices that do not support such optim, you will use the second version of your 'PieView', where the onDraw method draws its content on a transparent buffer bitmap first, before copying this bitmap on the canvas. This costly drawing will occur only once, and the unchanged bitmap will be reused on subsequent calls.
Of course, if any change must be made to this cache image (for instance if onSizeChanged is called), then it must be computed again.